# Does "hatcheries" mean "a farm where eggs are hatched under artificial conditions, especially those of fish or poultry"?

Tags: meaning

Ok, so

> A hatchery is a facility where eggs are hatched under artificial
>   conditions, especially those of fish or poultry - [Source (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatchery)

But I often see people use terms like "*Fish hatcheries*" or "*Poultry hatcheries*".

I am wondering why people use the plural "*hatcheries*" in this case.

So, does "*hatcheries*" mean "*a hatchering farm where eggs are hatched under artificial conditions, especially those of fish or poultry*"?

And of course, it is "*a hatchering farm*" because "*it has many facilities where eggs are hatched under artificial conditions, especially those of fish or poultry*"

The online dictionary only has the definition of the singular "*hatchery*", no definition of the plural "*hatcheries*".

Also, what is the word fitting to the meaning of "*a hatchering farm where eggs are hatched under artificial conditions, especially those of fish or poultry*" ?

Comment: What's wrong with the   the plural form? ***Fish hatcheries*** are used to cultivate and breed a large number of fish in an enclosed environment. ***Poultry hatcheries*** produce a majority of the birds consumed in the developed world including chickens, turkeys, ducks and some other minor bird species. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatchery

Comment: I want to know whether "hatcheries" means "a farm where eggs are hatched under artificial conditions, especially those of fish or poultry"

Comment: No it doesn't. 'Hatcheries' means 'Farm**s** where eggs are hatched under artificial conditions, especially those of fish or poultry'

Comment: 'Hatcheries' is a simple plural. (Unfortunately, there are more than one of them). Your edit now mentions 'Hatchering': I've never come across this term - where did you find it?

Comment: [hatcheries](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hatcheries) and [hatchery](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hatchery#hatchery_1)

Comment: so just call it "a hatchering farm"?

Comment: @JHCL, a Vietnamese dictionary say "Fish Hatcheries" is a Fish hatchering farm. SO I deduced from it

Comment: Ah okay - a Google search reveals almost exclusively Asian usage, mostly in relation to the supply of equipment to the egg industry.  I have to say that it's not a widely used term in the UK at least, although its meaning is clear enough I suppose as a synonym for 'hatching'.

Comment: @JHCL, so Fish hatcheries= Fish hatching farm?

Comment: @user105551 - No. Fish hatcheries = Fish hatching farm**s**.

Comment: why plural "farms"? many farms? doe not make sense

Comment: A hatchery is a type of farm. One farm = one hatchery.

Comment: A hatchery is "a facility ....." not "a farm ..." see the Wiki definition

Comment: There are only 8 results in Google for ["hatchering farms"](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22hatchering+farm%22) and one of them stems from this post. There is no such expression! A [hatchery](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hatchery) is a type of  *farm* which cultivates and *hatches* different animal eggs. Dictionary.com clearly states that the plural form is *hatcheries*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hatcheries* is plural and designates multiple facilities; if you're speaking of a single facility you use the singular *hatchery*.

What is probably confusing you here is that singular *hatchery* may be used to designate ***either*** a single structure (or pool or henhouse or whatever) where hatching is carried out, ***or*** a *collection* of such structures at a single place.

This ambiguity is very common. An institution you refer to as ***a*** school, for instance, may include several school***s***—a law school, a medical school, a business school, a graduate school, an engineering school, and so forth. ***A*** single grain elevator may be expanded to comprise several elevator***s***, and you may then refer to the entire campus either as "Bunge's elevators at Hannibal" or as "Bunge's elevator at Hannibal".

At one time, in fact, it was not unusual to see an integrated collection of multiple facilities of the type *Z* referred to as ***a Zs***—singular article with plural noun. This is rare now, but you may still encounter something like this:

> He'd seen the remarkable transformation from a peacetime docks to a docks at war.

And at least one such use is still 'standard'—we speak of manufacturing facilities as ***a** steel work**s*** or ***an** auto work**s***.

Comment: great, so "works (used with a sing. or pl. verb): A factory, plant, or similar building or complex of buildings where a specific type of business or industry is carried on. Often used in combination: a steelworks." Eh? http://www.thefreedictionary.com/works

Comment: @user105551 Exactly. It's not likely today that you'll run across "a hatcheries"; but a hatchery may be a single unit or a complex.

Comment: I don't know if **a rapids** *(section of a river with a very swift and turbulent current)* falls into the same general class of such usages, but it seems to me using the singular there is a bit dated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A Google Books search on "a rapids" / 21st century yields ca. 80 actual results, only a handful of which are false hits or republications.

Comment: nah man, embarrassing is when you lose control of your bladder and accidentally pee your pants, if you're between 25 and 35.

Comment: @JoeBlow Embarassing is losing control of your terms and accidentally peeing on your sentence, if you're a professional writer.

Comment: if you do that i reckon just pass it off as a certain *street frisson* and up your rate

Comment: I thought singular **a rapids** sounded a bit C19, but [checking the trend using NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+rapids&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20rapids%3B%2Cc0) it seems to be primarily a C20 usage that peaked during WW2 (and has been declining ever since).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=riding+the+rapid%2Criding+the+rapids&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Criding%20the%20rapids%3B%2Cc0

Comment: More to the point: Searching for "a rapid" where "rapid" is a noun, rather than an adjective, yields bupkus. "a rapids" is rare, but "a rapid" nonexistent.